# Managing the starting and closing of multiple PHP scripts

Tags: php, batch-file, automation

What would be a preferred method for automatically running multiple PHP scripts at certain times during the day and then closing them at certain times during the evening? Example: Start script1.php at 10:00 automatically and close it at 20:00 automatically

Im using Windows Server 2012, currently using scheduled tasks for starting the scripts but I have no proper way to close specific PHP processes or scripts, I can just close random ones based on PID.

Is there some program perhaps that could be used for this?

Answer (score 0):

you could get the scripts to exit themselves. i'm guessing that some sort of loop runs in your script - within that loop, check the current time - and if it's after your desired 'stop' time, exit.